# Fiat Siena EL 2001 was starting but jerking very bad whist running

Tags: electrical, fiat

Fiat Siena EL 2001 model

It has a starting problem, I'm really desperate to get it running again, please help.

The car was starting and running but was jerking very bad when in 2nd gear.

The mechanic changed a coil pack and a sensor. When I went to check the car was not starting at all.

Comment: What sounds do you hear when you try to start the car?

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft - please remember not everyone speaks English as their first language. Somethings can get lost in translation. Always live by the first tenant of SE: *be nice*. Thank you :-)

Comment: @Paulster2 - t'was but a joke... (and Fiat is Fiat, in any language)

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft - No worries. We've been working hard on this little SE. We don't want to drive off new people, so forgive me a little. Camaro is still Camaro, but people still want to put an "e" in the middle of it. Things happen ;-)

Comment: There is a question about your vehicle that needs to get answered in order for you to get some help.  Could add a comment and answer @HandyHowie 's question above?  TIA